# Fluent Nnihbernate References as one-to-one

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, one-to-one

I have two tables that I want to use with one to one relation.

```
class ParentMap{
    public ParentMap(){
        References(x => x.ChildMap, "parent_id").Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

the child has no related mapping.

The problem is that the `parent_id` column is created at the parent and not at the child.

I can work, but it is not right logically.
What is the best way to map **one to one**  with references, I really searched (-;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HasOne` on the parent to map it as a `one-to-one` relationship. This would mean the join happens on the primary key of the tables and the primary keys would be synchronized when saving.

If this does not work for you, then an alternative method is to map:

**Parent**

```
public ParentMap()
{
    HasOne(x => x.Child)
        .PropertyRef(x => x.Parent)
        .Cascade.All();
}
```

**Child**

```
public ChildMap()
{
    References(x => x.Parent, "parent_id");
}
```

This would require you to have a property `Parent` on the child. One-to-one relationships are bidirectional.